# td data is not coming in single line

Tags: html, css, asp.net

in my web page td is not coming in single line
Weekly report for XYZ is  coming in 2 lines , i need it in one line 
Why label content is coming in next line?

o/p
    Weekly Report for
     Testing project

```
desired o/p

Weekly Report for <LabelData>


 <td align="center" style="width: 100%; color: black; font-size: 12pt; font-`enter code here`family: Trebuchet MS;
                font-style: italic; background: #E4AFC1; height: 5px;white-space:nowrap">
                <b>Weekly Report for  <asp:Label ID="lblPro" runat="server"></asp:Label></b>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table must be responsive.
If you put your td inside a table that is not responsive, your td width try to expand 100% inside the maximum table width wich is fixed. See these examples:

Wrong way

```
<table width="80px">
     <td width="100%">Weekly Report for Testing project</td> 
</table>
```

Right way

```
<table width="100%">
     <td width="30%">collumn 1</td>
     <td width="40%">collumn 2</td>
     <td width="30%">collumn 3</td> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `white-space: nowrap`

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; color: black; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-style: italic; background: #E4AFC1; height: 50px;">
   <b>Weekly Report for  <asp:Label ID="lblPro" runat="server"></asp:Label></b>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
td{white-space: nowrap}
```

see if that is what you whant

Comment: sorry , no changes . even though i used white-space:nowrap